# There should be a virtual clipboard so I can easily track questions that I'm interested in

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks

I have enough tabs open as it is, and it seems that when I find a question that I'm interested in and want to watch for a while I have to keep it open in a new tab, or try to find it again later. This starts to clutter up my tab bar pretty quickly.

I could add it to my favorites, but it's not a favorite and it'd be a hassle to add/remove items from there constantly.

I think it would be neat if there was a temporary place to throw these questions - kind of like a virtual clipboard where on the top menu I can pull down some sort of drop down menu and see (and easily remove) questions that I've pinned and want to keep an eye on temporarily.

Comment: Browsers have bookmarks, just for such things.

Comment: temporarily - 10 or 15 minutes. I think a bookmark is overkill for that - especially when developers already have bloated bookmarks.

Comment: Or favorite a question.

Comment: @Steve Exactly, while I use bookmarks for the most interesting SO Q/A (I don't like the Favorite option that much ...), I use a remote clickable clipboard extension similar to what OP is talking about. I've to admit it could be messy to include this in SO though.

Answer (score 5):

This is what the "favorite" [sic] icon is for.

It marks (to you) the question as one you are interested in and lists on your profile:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/users/<id>/<name>?tab=favorites
```

The favourite choice is not locked in, you can clear it at any time.

You should be using this option to:

- Check back on questions you down-voted to see if they've been improved. You might be able to remove the vote.
- Check back on questions you voted to close to see if they've been improved. You might be able to vote to reopen.

as well as the more traditional:

- I'm interested in answers to this question as well.

Comment: This is a very valid option, I just found it a bit clunky or a hassle (not that I'm not appreciative of the option) to view my favorites - have to go to my profile, find it in my favorites (and yes I could sort it chronologically), so maybe what I'm really asking is for a better way to interact with my favorites instead of additional functionality